# How to change UITabBar items text in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I have a UITabBar as an outlet

```
  @IBOutlet weak var tabbar: UITabBar!
```

I repeat i dont want to change the text of tab item of `UITabBarController`.But of `UITabBar`

How can i change the text of UITabBar Item not from storyboard because of my Localization functionality...

Comment: do you wanna set title of UITabBar Item?

Comment: its already answered here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407590/programmatically-setting-tabbaritem-title-in-swift

Comment: oops..i didnot know that...post that as an aswer with the link...

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407590/programmatically-setting-tabbaritem-title-in-swift]

Answer (score 0):

Try 
For Tab bar

self.title=@"tab bar name";

For Navigation Bar

self.navigationItem.title = "HipHop";